# How do I get debug messages out of a Qt Plugin?

Tags: windows, debugging, qt, plugins, dll

I am trying to get GIF write support working on my Qt Windows application.

I have compiled the 3rd party image plugin project:

https://gitorious.org/qt-gif-plugin

Whilst the reading is working, the writing is not.  I want to get debug messages out, in my main I have installed a qInstallMsgHandler() so that I can see debug messages on the console.  However how do I do the same for the compiled DLL?

Answer (score 0):

how about re-directing output to a log file, using qInstallMsgHandler?

Answer (score 0):

I use qDebug output statements in my Qt C++ compiled plugins.  Then I use sysinternals debugview free utility to monitor the output at run-time.